# Struts tags doesn't allow Scriptlets in the tag's attributes

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have the following piece of code in an JSP page of my project,

```jsp
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<% String var="hello"; %>         
<c:set var="test1" value="<%= var %>"/>
<s:set var="test2" value=" <%=var%>" />
<script>
 document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML="${test1}"; //hello
 document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML="${test2}"; //nothing is displayed.
</script>
```

My doubt is both `<c:set..>` tag and `<s:set..>` tag is executed by the same container,
 but why the first one produces the result as  "hello" and later doesnot gives any result.

Answer (score 0):

Every thing fine.you are not giving  tag properly in the second case.

Your code

```
<s:set var="test2" value=" <%=var%>" />
```

Change it to

```
<c:set var="test2" value=" <%=var%>" />
```

Basically we display a struts variable using following syntax try this

```
<s:property   value="test2"/>
```

Comment: I have given the correct tag <s:set..> tag,it is a struts 2 tag.

Comment: May i know why you trying to mix both?Why you cant use JSTL tag there in the second case?

Comment: I can use JSTL tag there, but my doubt is cam we use expreression language in <s:set..> tag or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest Scriptlets, nor other Struts Tags, inside a Struts Tag.

But you can open the tag and put it in the middle:

```xml
<s:set var="test2" >
    <%=var%>
</s:set>
```

Comment: why we cant nest scriptlet in a struts tag whereas we can nest  scriptlet in a JSTL tag.whats the reason.